# How to fix "failed to open stream" error after php artisan serve?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new with laravel.

I install composer and when I run `php artisan serve` in root project it gives me this error:

> PHP Warning:  require(/home/d/blog/vendor/autoload.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in /home/d/blog/artisan on line
>   18 PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/d/blog/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')
>   in /home/d/blog/artisan on line 18

How can I fix this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I install composer"? What did you do?

Comment: You just need to run `composer install` in the project directory which will create a folder named `vendor` which will have all composer libraries and `autoload.php` file.

Comment: @AkshayKhale i try it  but same error